# rpy2 returns "No" in the FactorVector returned by the predict function

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am trying to export a model created in R to Python using rpy2. Found a couple of tutorials and this is how I'm doing the conversion in Python:

```py
r = robjects.r
numpy2ri.activate()

MODEL_PATH = "test_model"
model_rds_path = "{}.rds".format(MODEL_PATH)
model_dep_path = "{}.dep".format(MODEL_PATH)

model = r.readRDS(model_rds_path)

with open(model_dep_path, "rt") as f:
    model_dep_list = [importr(dep.strip()) for dep in f.readlines() if dep.strip()!='']

def predict(X):
    if type(X) is not np.ndarray:
        X = np.array(X)

    pred = r.predict(model, X, probability=True)
    return pred

# Example Input
X = np.array([
    [22.3,35.6,0,9.2,12.8,"NE",44,"WNW","NE",13,28,53,32,1015.2,1011.4,0,0,28.4,34.7,"No"], # No
    [23.8,33.3,0,8,10.4,"NNW",33,"E","NNW",7,20,63,53,1014.7,1010.4,1,1,29.2,31.4,"No"], # Yes
])

pred = predict(X)

print(pred)
```

The return value is a FactorVector and rpy2's documentation suggests that it should contain integer values with labels. But this is what I get as the output:

```
No No
Levels: No Yes
```

I think I'm doing something wrong here; not only because of the string values returned but more importantly, no matter what I pass as input, the prediction is No. The model is fine though - it returns the correct FactorVector when I run and pass the same input in R.

You can find the R code used to create the model and rds file here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3YC9XKvQjV/